# Why can't I ping 192.168.0.3 while NET USE is fine?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-7, ping

I shared a folder c:\users\ on a Windows 7 desktop that is connected to a cable modem/wireless router. I have an XP desktop cabled to the same modem/router. It's an ARRIS or Motorola Surfboard SBG6580 that I just bought used. Both (desktop) boxes get internet fine.

In order to reach the W7 box files, on an XP prompt I go
`NET USE \\\192.168.0.3\users`
and
`SUBST Q: "\\\192.168.0.3\users\Bob"`

Those work flawlessly. Since I gave full access when I shared the Win7 folder, I can read and write to everything by using Q: on the XP box.

But since replacing the modem (same brand/model as before), `ping` doesn't work anymore. The IPs have not changed. (By the way it could be a coincidence that this began when I swapped out the modem, because I didn't try the `ping` until a week later.) Anyway, now,
`ping 192.168.0.3 -n 1 -w 1000`
gets 100% loss each and every time.

I went through every single screen after browsing/logging into the modem at `http://192.168.0.1` and don't see that I'm blocking anything anywhere. It has a setting for IPv4 Firewall Protection which I changed from Low to Off. (When it was Low, I had Port Scan Detection checked.) Anyway, that screen says "No Ports Restricted."

Also `tracert 192.168.0.3 -w 200` 
times out every time, in case that's meaningful. `arp -a` shows nothing about address 192.168.0.3. (both run on the XP box)

I've turned off the 3rd party XP software firewall (which had whitelisted `ping` anyway). Restarted both boxes and the modem.

Small note, `NET USE` reports status "Disconnected" sometimes even though I know the connection is good. If I go `DIR Q:` and immediately go `NET USE` again, this time it reports OK. I assume that's just a peculiarity with `NET USE`.

EDIT: Thanks for the ICMP suggestion but 192.168.0.1 pings okay as does 192.168.0.2 as does google.com. It's not that all PINGs fail; just this one.

Comment: tracert and ping both use ICMP, which is a different protocol than TCP which is what your SMB sharing utilizes. ICMP is frequently blocked to prevent network enumeration.

Comment: What is it blocked by? (I turned off both the modem/router and XP software firewalls.) What steps should I take? Forgive me, I'm an IP novice, so simple suggestions might help.

Comment: @MicrosoftShouldBeKickedInNuts It could be blocked by any firewall between source and target,

Answer (score 0):

The firewall on `192.168.0.3` was mistakenly set to block incoming ICMP packets.

Comment: But the software firewall is off; the modem/router firewall is off. How should I proceed?